# Build-in views?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I installed a module to Django and this module has ceertain views within itself. Also it comes with a demo to see the features. I am looking at the code from the demo for a while now but I cant figure out how a template is rendered over the build in views.

The module i'm working with is swingtime: 
Here is an example: 
Excerpt from the template:

```
<a class="plain" href="{% url 'swingtime-daily-view' prev_day.year prev_day.month prev_day.day %}">
```

URL Directory

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',                  TemplateView.as_view(template_name='intro.html'), name='demo-home'),
    url(r'^karate/',            include('karate.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/',             include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^docs/?$',            RedirectView.as_view(url='/docs/index.html', permanent=True)),
    url(r'^docs/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, dict(document_root=doc_root, show_indexes=False))
]
```

So the url must somehow link to a built-in template i suppose? 
When I try to implement similar code in my project the url can not be reversed?

And also: How would one edit the template for such a build in view? 
Thank you!

Comment: Check urls.py in karate module. You'll find a url with `name="swingtime-daily-view"`. View related to this url contains the logic for rendering the template.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but there is also new url with this name in the karate module.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='karate.html'), name='karate-home'),
    url(r'^swingtime/events/type/([^/]+)/$', views.event_type, name='karate-event'),
    url(r'^swingtime/', include('swingtime.urls')),
]

Comment: ah, now i see the include line of code which links the swingtime urls with the demo karate urls. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the urls.py file in the karate module. you  will find the url there.

It will be something like

```
urlpatterns = [
        ...
        url(r'daily-view', view='view_name' name='swingtime-daily-view'),
...
]
```

Now the name argument of the url is the important thing you're looking for as I don't know the actual path or view set there.

So when you have something like this

```
<a class="plain" href="{% url 'swingtime-daily-view' prev_day.year prev_day.month prev_day.day %}">
```

The url dispatcher will look through the app urls for the url with this view....this is called named url patterns.

Read more on how url patterns work [URL DISPATCHER IN DJANGO](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/)